# Unity can't acess another class 's instance c#

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

The first class

```
public class ArmyManMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public Animator anim;
    TextInput check;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();

    }
```

The second class

```
public class TextInput : MonoBehaviour 
{

    ArmyManMovement check;
    void Awake()
    {
        check = GetComponent<ArmyManMovement> ();
        //check.anim.SetBool ("Right", false);
    }
    //public  IEnumerable<string> RemoveWhitespace(string input)
    //{
        //return new string(input.ToCharArray().Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
    //}

    void AcceptStringInput(string userInput)
    {
        userInput = userInput.ToLower ();
        if (userInput == "Open door") {
            check.anim.SetBool("Right",true);

        }
```

}

I don't know what 's wrong.I attached the Armyman 's script to the same inspector where textinput is.I don't know what 's wrong,but the value doesn't change and i can't access the animator in armyman 's script.It keeps priniting in the console that the error is (Object refrence not set to instance of object)

Comment: You do realize that your check for `if (userInput == "Open door")` will always fail, since that contains upper-case characters and in the previous line you made `userInput` all lower-case?

Comment: changed it,still the problem isn't solved.This isn't the issue

Comment: i am 100% it enters the conditon ,this isn't the case here

Comment: Yes, it was just a side comment, not for the main issue. I'll delete it now, just wanted you to know

Comment: @RufusL You don't have to delete that since that's also an issue in the code. Didn't cover it because you did in the comment section.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAmhawy Do not forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer if this answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

If the `ArmyManMovement` is attached to the-same GameObject the TextInput  script is attached to, it should **never** be `null` when you perform `GetComponent<ArmyManMovement> ();` from the `TextInput` script.

There are really two possible problems here:

**1**.The `TextInput` script is also attached to another GameObject. Look in your scene and make sure that it is not. If it is mistakenly attached to another GameObject that that does not have the `ArmyManMovement` attached to it too, `GetComponent<ArmyManMovement> ();` will return `null` which mean that the `check` variable will be `null`. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p75t8.gif) for how to find this out and fix it.

**2**.The `anim` variable is not assigned from the Editor.

First test: `Debug.Log(check);`.

If it is not `null` then test: `Debug.Log(check.anim);`.

If that is `null` then drag your animator to the anim slot in the `ArmyManMovement` script.

Note that if `Debug.Log(check);` is `null`, you need to go back to **#1** and fix that first. Hopefully, you now know how to fix your future Unity `null` problems.